# How to Set download Path in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I'm downloading html file with the content of a div. It's working perfectly but only issue is that it's downloading file in downloads folder instead i want it to download in the folder where project exists.

Here is the code of download function:

```
function download(){
    var a = document.body.appendChild(
        document.createElement("a")
    );
    a.download = "design.html";
    a.href = "data:text/html," + document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML; 
    a.click(); 
}
```

Comment: Then I would recommend to do this using PHP file functions. generate the file you want to get downloaded and move it to the folder you want. And on the page show an alert saying: "Your file has been saved at 'path of the file'"

Comment: Also i have to access that file later, so can you provide me code for that?

Comment: You can set the file path to <a> tag and it will get downloaded on user's system.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot control where the user have to download the file to. It's user's choice.

Comment: This should be in comments. This is not an answer.

Comment: Looks like an answer to me. @HimanshuUpadhyay How is it not? tbh it could be much shorter, something like *no, it cant be done, if it could think of the security risks*..

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Should be a comment if the goal is to make OP provide more information. Here it looks like an answer. Some questions are like that - there is no way to answer them without just stating "it is not possible".